# Mongodb group by multiple keys to get unique documents in collection

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have collection and documents are structured in the following format:

```
[
 {

    "brand" : "Toshiba",
    "title" : "Toshiba Pors 7220CT / NW2",
    "category" : "notebooks",
    "code" : "ABCDTESTASD12",
    "pid" : "45790"
 }, 
 {
    "brand" : "Toshiba",
    "title" : "Toshiba Satellite Pro 4600 PIII800",
    "category" : "notebooks",
    "ean" : "PATDSRESSSN12",
    "pid" : "12345"
 }
]
```

Could you suggest me the query to find unique documents which have same brand,title,category,code so that I can see unique docs in collection.

Comment: is this a single document? can you show the expected result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the aggregation pipeline stages have **[maximum memory use limit](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-memory-limit)**, use the following pipeline which deals with large datasets by setting `allowDiskUse` option to true thus enables writing data to temporary files.
Within the pipeline, use the [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match) stage to filter out dupes so that you only remain with the unique documents which you can query by `_id`:

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": { /* Group by fields to match on brand, title, category and code */
            "_id": { 
                "brand": "$brand", 
                "title": "$title", 
                "category": "$category", 
                "code": "$code" 
            },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }, /* Count number of matching docs for the group */
            "docs": { "$push": "$_id" }, /* Save the _id for matching docs */
            "pids": { "$push": "$pid" } /* Save the matching pids to list */
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "count": 1 } }, /* filter out dupes */
    { "$out": "result" } /* Output aggregation results to another collection */
],
options = { "allowDiskUse": true, cursor: {} };

db.products.aggregate(pipeline, options); // Run the aggregation operation

db.result.find(); // Get the unique documents
```

Comment: chridam it is not returning any results.

Comment: sorry Chridam it's my mistake. It is working fine. Thank you.

Comment: need small help. Can I get list of pids for each result doc?

Comment: @ArvindKumarAnugula Yes, you can use another `$push` operation in the `$group` to create a list of the matching `pid`. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine.  but it is taking more than 2 min for 1 Million records. can you suggest me how I can improve performance.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAnugula No worries. Consider posting separately as this is another issue.

Comment: posted separate question. Could you check into that.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the group operator from the aggregation framework:

```
db.computers.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $group : {
                _id : { brand: "$brand", title: "$title", category: "$category", code: "$code" },
                count: { $sum: 1 }
            }
        }
    ]
)
```

Comment: Thanks AleFranz  for your query. I have 5 million documents and it is returning error like: " exception: Exceeded memory limit for $group, but didn't allow external sort. Pass allowDiskUse:true to opt in."

Comment: You could fix it adding a second parameter to aggregate(): {allowDiskUse:true, cursor:{}}

Comment: Added but returning same issue

Comment: Which version are you using? You need at least mongoDB 2.6. also you client/shell need to be for 2.6+

Comment: I'm using Mongodb 3.0.6 version and client Robomongo 0.8.5 version. If I run it on shell it is working fine but taking more than 1 minute time.

Comment: Run for each category rather than running on a whole. Index wont help much as you not matching anything